# Making a low-cost in situ fluorometer with Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, photodiode, arduino-uno, datalogger

I am making a low cost *in situ* fluorometer with Arduino based on this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/13/6/7872)

The paper lists all the instruments required for the device, but since some of the products were outdated/hard to find, I replaced the items mentioned below:

- Arduino Duemilanove -> [Keyestudio Plus Board](https://wiki.keyestudio.com/KS0486_Keyestudio_PLUS_Development_Board_(Black_And_Eco-friendly))
- Photodiode (FDS100) -> [Si PIN photodiode (S1223-01)](https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/s1223_series_kpin1050e.pdf)
- Two 5G resistors -> Ten 1G resistors
- Operational amplifier -> [Operational amplifier OP07 CPZ](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/225187/AD/OP07CPZ.html)

Using these tools, I followed the schematic presented in the paper by Leeuw et al.(2013).

[image: Figure 3 from Leeuw et al., 2013.]

However, the analog input only read values in the range of 140 - 200, and it does not seem to be amplifying the signal from the photodiode.

I checked the values when only the photodiode is connected to Arduino, and reads the values in the range of 58 (completely dark) to 94 (flashed with iphone torch).

I used the following code to check the analog input:

```
int phd = A0;

void setup(void) {
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
     
}
 
void loop(void) {
   
  int phdValue = analogRead(phd);

  Serial.print("Phd Value: ");
  Serial.println(phdValue);
  delay(300);
   
}
```

These are the list of things I checked to make sure that the fluorometer will work.

1. Connected the OP07 amplifier V+ end to 5V and the V- end to GND
2. The Data logger shield works perfectly fine

The issue might to do with the wiring of the amplifier or the resistance, as I have not yet encountered anyone using a resistance greater than 1G ohms for this kind of project.

Thank you.

Comment: 5.3 nA offset current times 10 Gohm = 53 V. This won't be easy with that large input impedance. Can you go lower?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried using 10k ohm in the circuit (20k ohm in total) but the minimum was 520 and the maximum was 540. Do you think I should use different resistor values within the circuit (Ex. 10k ohms and 1G ohms)?

Comment: You are welcome! You can fairly easily simulate this with an ideal op-amp and add the typical (for a one-off) or worst-case (for mass production) values of offset and input current and see how it affects your circuit and how much offsets and non-linearity you can accept. 1 Gohm will always be difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will try and simulate it with different resistor values.